# Changing select field selectedIndex in filtered field

Tags: javascript, jquery

My select field is filtered as below:

```
 $("#asortyment option").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
```

To change selected option I use code:

```
  function wiecej(){
    var asort_select = document.getElementById("asortyment");
    asort_select.selectedIndex = asort_select.selectedIndex + 1;  
    $("#asortyment").trigger("change");
  };
```

But the problem is that function wiecej change option to next but in not filtered select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jQuery `:visible` pseudo-class to match the non-filtered elements. And use `:gt` to start after the currently selected option.

```js
function wiecej() {
  var asort_select = document.getElementById("asortyment");
  let current = asort_select.selectedIndex;
  let next = $(`#asortyment option:gt(${current}):visible`).first();
  if (next.length > 0) {
    $(asort_select).val(next.val()).change();
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to change to the previous option?

Comment: Use `:lt` and `.last()` in place of `:gt` and `.first()`

Comment: But code works only in Firefox. In Chrome and Edge line code  $(asort_select).val(next.val()).change(); does not change selected option to next.

Answer (score 0):

Filter visible options and then change selected index:

```
function wiecej(){
    var asort_select = document.getElementById("asortyment");
    var nextItem = $("#asortyment option:gt("+asort_select.selectedIndex+")").filter(function(){ return $(this).css('display') != 'none';}).first();
    var nextIndex = 0;
    if (nextItem.length > 0 ) {
        nextIndex = nextItem[0].index;
    } else {
        var nextItem = $("#asortyment option").filter(function(){ return $(this).css('display') != 'none';}).first();
        nextIndex = nextItem[0].index;
    }
    asort_select.selectedIndex = nextIndex;  
    $("#asortyment").trigger("change");
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).